# Using ASP.NET Forms Authentication, how do I get an image to appear on the login screen?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-2.0

I am doing simple forms authentication for a small ASP.NET (3.5, C#) application and setting up my usernames and passwords in the web.config.

I would like to apply the default stylesheet and include the header graphic (included on every other page) but the graphic and stylesheet won't apply, presumably because the anonymous user doesn't have access to those two files.  Is there some easy way for me to add them or some other way to make the image appear on the page?

Here is the relevent section of the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" 
    path="/" 
    loginUrl="login.aspx" 
    protection="All" timeout="30">

    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
      <user
          name="testuser"
          password="hashgoeshere"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

The stylesheet is at:
/stylesheet.css
and the image is at:
/img/logoimage.png

Thanks.  This site makes me happy because hopefully it will make Experts Exchange and their lame paywall DIE!

Comment: hint on paywall... use google cached result to get the content you're looking for.

Comment: Or, just use stack overflow and let Experts Exchange die a slow and painful death.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add exceptions in your Web.Config using location-specific rules (add these after the System.Web section):

```
<location path="stylesheet.css">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<location path="img/">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: I would like to point that the location path cannot end in a / this will generate an error.  Other than that, this is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks :)