# asp.net authorization problem authorizes everyone

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

So I got 2 .aspx files. One called login and one called default. The idea is that when you start up the application you will be kicked to the Login screen. I'm doing this with the following code in the default.aspx.vb file:

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        If (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = False) Then

            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")


        End If

    End Sub
```

Problem is that you're always authenticated for some reason. It always returns true.
My web Config file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="strConn" value="EDITED"/>

  </appSettings>
  <location path="~/Styles">
    <system.web>




  <customErrors mode ="Off">

  </customErrors>

  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXAUTH"
           loginUrl="Login.aspx"
           protection="All"
           timeout="30"
           path="/">
    </forms>
  </authentication>

  <authorization>

    <deny users="?" />
    <allow users="*" />

  </authorization>
  <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="Microsoft.Data.Odbc, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      <add assembly="system.web.security"/>

    </assemblies>
  </compilation>



 </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I've tried with   aswell didn't change anything. The users gets authenticated through a database. Currently I am running the program in Visual studio, not on my website. When the users has been checked through the database I use this code:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, chkPersistCookie.Checked)
```

So any idea why people are always authorized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the location tag. You're only applying these rules to the Styles directory, not the entire site.

Comment: Where should it be then? I don't have visual studio where I am now. But I will test tormorrow. Can you tell me where location tags are normally put?

Comment: You should probably just remove the location tag. What you're doing is saying that all those settings just apply to the Styles directory. I can't imagine that's what you want.

Comment: Hmm but now I lost the CSS on all my files, the good news is that everything else works now, after 1 week of trying to figure this out, it was just a silly location tag.. :p God that feels good =)

Comment: I figured out my problem with the CSS. Forms blocks all folders until you have been authenticated. But as the post above you can throw these folders into Location tags which will allow the folders to be used. Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485735/using-asp-net-forms-authentication-how-do-i-get-an-image-to-appear-on-the-login

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to write any code to perform the redirection when not logged in.  The framework is smart enough to look at the authentication, and log you in.

Two items to note:

Change this:

```
<deny users="*" />
```

to:

```
<deny users="?" />
<allow users="*" />
```

This denies only unauthenticated users.

Se if that makes a difference and the second item to check is the user info.  In immediate window, enter:

HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationMode //or similarly named, forget exact name

And see what it tells you... also what type of  object is Identity?  Is it GenericIdentity, FormsIdentity, or WindowsIdentity?

Thanks.

Comment: I changed <deny users="*" /> to <deny users="?" />
<allow users="*" /> but I still have the same problem. Deny ? means no strangers are allowed. But what does allow * do?

Thereafter i Tried this HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType, and the returned value was NTLM. As I'm totally new at asp.net I have no clue what this is, maybe you can tell me? :)

Then I tried this HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetType to get the type of Identity which is System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.

Is this what you wanted? :)

Comment: oh and the Name, I get from the identity is Unreal\Admin. Which is the name of my computer and the username of my user account on this computer. I actually had an earlier question on this site on how to change this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152735/saving-the-login-name-as-current-user-identity-in-asp-net .

Comment: Yes, it's using windows authentication, not forms authentication.  An <allow users="*" /> after a deny means allow all authenticated users (processed in the order of: deny unauthenticated, allow all, and these rules are processed in order).

Comment: I'm not sure why its using windows over forms, but that's what NTLM security is... so double-check your config file again.

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
               loginUrl="Login.aspx"
               protection="All"
               timeout="30"
               path="/"/>
       
      </authentication>

that's an exact copy paste of my web config file.. Any ideas? It's not like there is somewhere else I have to write "forms" is there?

Comment: I just edited my first post to contain my full config file.. do you see anything that shouldn't be there?